# Use placeholders and $wpdb->prepare(); found interpolated variable $now

Tags: wordpress, phpcodesniffer

I have a problem with placeholders in $wpdb->get_results. With the code below I have all the results correctly but I have an error when I use the code sniffer

```
$now = current_time('mysql', true);

$allPosts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT
        YEAR(post_date_gmt) AS `year`,
        MONTH(post_date_gmt) AS `month`,
        MAX(post_date_gmt) AS last_mod,
        count(ID) AS posts
    FROM
        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE
        post_date_gmt < '$now'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_type = 'post'
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(post_date_gmt),
        MONTH(post_date_gmt)
    ORDER BY
        post_date_gmt DESC
");
```

I tried to change with %s and $now in the end but no results are shown

```
$allPosts = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT
        YEAR(post_date_gmt) AS `year`,
        MONTH(post_date_gmt) AS `month`,
        MAX(post_date_gmt) AS last_mod,
        count(ID) AS posts
    FROM
        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE
        post_date_gmt < %s
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_type = 'post'
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(post_date_gmt),
        MONTH(post_date_gmt)
    ORDER BY
        post_date_gmt DESC
", $now);
```

I know I can resolve it by omitted **post_date_gmt < %s** but I'd like to know how I can resolve it with post_date_gmt < %s?

Comment: why didn't you don't use get_posts or wp_query?

Comment: because I have to get all years and months of all posts published. With wp_query o get_posts an error occurs because the results are so much

Comment: with get_posts it may happen, because it returns all results at once. But wp_query stream the results, it should work.